# NodeJS Array not filling up

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express

Im using mongodb as a database after getting the valuation data which are more then one , i loop inside them and get the offers according to the offres_id , I asure you that the database has data inside and to querys are working correctly in fact if i console log them in each iteration i get this result

```
{
  offre: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("63320bf87123db5691c51392"),
      user_id: '63304e44aa63c519d887dac1',
      brand: 'HP',
      model: 'AZGGH-89855A',
      photo: '16642242480661659650294043-bs-5.png', 
      scan_method: 'manual',
      __v: 0
    }
  ],
  valuation: {
    _id: new ObjectId("63320d39a5677df3cebcbdae"),
    user_id: '63304e44aa63c519d887dac1',
    offre_id: '63320bf87123db5691c51392',
    given_price: '1236',
    comment: 'no comment',
    __v: 0
  }
}
{
  offre: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("6334202a8c7e6d90b35ee999"),
      user_id: '63304e44aa63c519d887dac1',
      brand: 'DELL',
      model: 'AZGGH-89855A',
      photo: '1664360490280Capture.PNG',
      scan_method: 'manual',
      __v: 0
    }
  ],
  valuation: {
    _id: new ObjectId("633420be8c7e6d90b35ee99e"),
    user_id: '63304e44aa63c519d887dac1',
    offre_id: '6334202a8c7e6d90b35ee999',
    __v: 0
  }
}
```

but when i try storing each offre & valuation at the same array cell and return it i get this as a result

> []

However this is the code

```
router.get('/get', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        Valuation.find({ user_id: req.session.userID })
            .exec()
            .then(valuation => {
                let myData = []; 
                if (valuation) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < valuation.length; i++) {
                        Offre.find({_id : valuation[i].offre_id})
                        .exec()
                        .then(offre=>{
                            myData.push({offre : offre, valuation : valuation[i]})
                        })
                    }
                    res.status(200).json(myData)
                   


                } else {
                    res.status(404).json('no valuations found')
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                res.status(500).json(error.message)
            })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: error.message })
    }
})
```

Comment: did you check with console.log offre have the data? maybe data not fetched from DB

Comment: i checked its returning data

Comment: Its just executing the response before the promise is resolve, so myData is still empty in the moment that you response. Check how promise works on nodejs, you should wait until the promise is resolve. Try to put res.status(200).json(myData) inside the then block (2 lines up)

Comment: worked but its only returning first offre & valuation with this error

Comment: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: that error is because im still trying to send more data while headers(res.status(200).json(myData) already send in the first iteration

Comment: because you put it in for loop and first time when loop complete its give response so before send response check for loop completed or not `if(i==valuation.length-1)` after that send response

Comment: If you're using `async`, why are you not using `await`?

Comment: i tried using await no result

Comment: @PriyankaSankhala if i return the data inside foor loop it will return first line the crash & if i put it outside of the foor loop it will return nothing

Comment: @gary then you didn't use it correctly.

Comment: @robertklep i used it like this 
await myData.push({offre : offre, valuation : valuation[i]})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using `async`, it would be a shame to not use `await` to simplify your code:

```
router.get("/get", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const valuation = await Valuation.find({ user_id: req.session.userID }).exec();
    if (valuation) {
      let myData = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < valuation.length; i++) {
        const offre = await Offre.find({ _id: valuation[i].offre_id }).exec();
        myData.push({ offre: offre, valuation: valuation[i] });
      }
      res.status(200).json(myData);
    } else {
      res.status(404).json("no valuations found");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});
```

You can probably also speed up the `Offre` query by using an `$in` query to retrieve all offres with one query, but that's another thing.

Comment: Thank you i know what is await and when do we use it ,but still i never thought of using it there ,thank you again for your help

Comment: @gary well, if you used `await` on `myData.push()` I don't think you exactly know when to use it ;)

Comment: in despread times i use despread solutions (i said thank you stop roasting me xD)